# ImportError: cannot import name 'TFBertModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use a tensorflow model with huggingface transformers. No success so far... Any hint would be appreciated !

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>> from transformers import TFBertModel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TFBertModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)
>>>
```

Comment: With Tensorflow 2.4.1, i could able to import TFBertModel from transformers. Thanks!